# Lighthouse - robots.txt error Syntax not understood

Tags: html, web, testing, frontend

When I test [my website](https://ameer-taweel.firebaseapp.com/) with `Lighthouse` it gives me that it found 50 errors with robots.txt, and I don't know what are the problems and how to solve them. It shows the content of my index.html file with error for each line. **What is the problem? And how to solve it??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, had a similar problem lately. All I had to do was to generate `robots.txt` manually. Just google it - `generate robots.txt`. Then upload it to your app. Would be also nice to generate `sitemap.xml`.

If u're too lazy, u can just copy and paste following code:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /example  // example is directory u want to exclude, 
                    // if u dont want to exclude anything, just remove this line

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```